# Java 9: Creating Spring Boot App with different modules

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, java-9

I am having a Spring Boot App with Java 9.

Depending on the input parameter to maven, I want to create the Spring Boot App Jar with different modules.

Example: I have four modules mod1, mod2, mod3, and mod4. If I pass the parameter 'light' then the Spring Boot App should have mod1 and mod2 modules only and If I pass a parameter 'full' it should create spring boot jar with all the modules i.e build mod1, mod2, mod3, and mod4.

Is this possible?

Comment: Building a Spring Boot App with modules does not make sense cause the resulting jar contains all code which means there is no separation of modules possible apart from that a single JAR can only contains a single `module-info.java` which makes it useless...Furthermore if you need to have two different spring boot apps you should make to spring boot modules in your build and do things like profiles etc....

Comment: You can create a project with multiple maven and java modules for a clean layered application.  I've seen multiple youtubes on it.  However, I have yet to find the secret to separate the MVC from SpringApplication class.  I would like multiple MVC modules that run on the same port so I only want one app.

Answer (score 0):

Maven profiles will help. http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html
You can make profiles as per your need and then can use "maven assembly plugin" to build the modules as per your need.
This link [Maven maven-assembly-plugin build with profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37785455/maven-maven-assembly-plugin-build-with-profile) can help.